# Nested XML structures from list of dicts in Python 3

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a list of dictionaries, and I would like to create an XML structure from it. Below is a sample of what I have tried. The main issue is that I cannot get out of the element "item" (I am probably not using the correct terms, please, forgive me in advance):

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

mapping = [
    {"struct": "root\\item\\itemno"},
    {"struct": "root\\item\\itemdup"},
    {"struct": "root\\item\\edge\\type"},
    {"struct": "root\\item\\edge\\len\\l1"},
    {"struct": "root\\item\\edge\\len\\l2"},
]

# The first item will always be the root
root = ET.Element(mapping[0]["struct"].split("\\")[0])

for structure in mapping:
    structure = structure["struct"].split("\\")
    # remove the first element, root, as this was already added
    del structure[0]
    iter = 1
    for element in structure:
        print("Element being processed", element)
        if not root.findall(element):
            if iter == 1:
                sub = ET.SubElement(root, element)
                print(f"iter {iter} - element not found in root {element} - Added to ROOT")
            else:
                ET.SubElement(sub, element)
                print(f"iter {iter} - element not found in root {element} - Added to SUB")
        else:
            print(f"iter {iter} - element found {element}")
        iter += 1

ET.dump(root)
```

The result I get from this is the following:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <itemno />
    <itemdup />
    <edge />
    <type />
    <edge />
    <len />
    <l1 />
    <edge />
    <len />
    <l2 />
  </item>
</root>
```

What I would like is the following:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <itemno />
    <itemdup />
    <edge>
      <type />
      <len>
        <l1 />
        <l2 />
      </len>
    </edge>
  </item>
</root>
```

It starts well, but when it gets to "type" it goes inside "item" and not "edge".

I put some print statements to help me debug it but I could not figure it out.

I have already looked into similar issues in SO, but the main problem is that my list changes, so I don't always know the name of the element I must search for and where to place it.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. It should show you where can be the problem.

Comment: you should at start set `sub = root` and later use `sub = ET.SubElement(sub, element)` to create nested elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested elements so you should create it in differet way

for every structure first set

```
 sub = root
```

and later if `item` doesn't exist then create new item and get it as `sub`

```
 sub = ET.SubElement(sub, element)
```

and if `item` exists then get it

```
 sub = item
```

---

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

mapping = [
    {"struct": "root\\item\\itemno"},
    {"struct": "root\\item\\itemdup"},
    {"struct": "root\\item\\edge\\type"},
    {"struct": "root\\item\\edge\\len\\l1"},
    {"struct": "root\\item\\edge\\len\\l2"},
]

# The first item will always be the root
root = ET.Element(mapping[0]["struct"].split("\\")[0])

for structure in mapping:
    structure = structure["struct"].split("\\")
    # remove the first element, root, as this was already added
    del structure[0]

    sub = root
    for element in structure:
        print("Element:", element)
        item = sub.find(element)
        if not item:
            sub = ET.SubElement(sub, element)
        else:
            sub = item
    print('---')

#ET.dump(root)

from xml.dom import minidom
text = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="  ")
print(text)
```

Comment: Thank you @furas ! I was missing the part where I actually reset it back to root. not to mention your code is much cleaner. Also thank you for `print debugging` :)